# How to keep start process in docker container on unix server

Tags: python, process, rabbitmq, pika

I created Docker container on unix server which reading messages from rabbitMQ using pika, it is time consuming process (it means to execute one id it will take 5 - 7 min).

```
nohup python3 sales_of years.py 1
nohup python3 sales_of years.py 2
nohup python3 sales_of years.py 3  .......
```

Its automatically killed in some time, No error is coming just consumers is getting killed, I just wanted to keep start all consumers

How Should I fix this issue.

Thanks In Advance...!

Comment: guys need attention for a while....can u..?

Comment: please share your dockerfile and commands you use to start and simulate the issue. 
this way, it will be fully reproducible and we might help